# What hose do I use to connect my GE dishwasher to my sink's 3/4" Tee?

Tags: plumbing, drain, dishwasher

I recently purchased a new GE dishwasher to replace our old dishwasher. The model we bought is GDF530PGMWW. It comes with a drain hose attached (see image), and it comes with an extension hose. The sink end of the extension hose does not fit the existing Tee on our sink's drain. I purchased a universal drain hose from Home Depot and that fits on the sink's Tee (3/4"), but not on the end of the dishwasher's drain hose. Is there some kind of adapter that can change the size? It appears the drain hose that's attached is 7/8".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll want a barbed connector similar to this one:

[image]
<sup>Image courtesy of Lowes.com. Note that's *not* the right size, *nor* is it an adapter, it's just for illustration purposes.
No endorsement intended or implied.</sup>

You'll want it to have a 3/4" barb on one end and 7/8" on the other end. You can use either plastic or brass, it doesn't matter.

I'd also suggest that you pick up hose clamps to put around where the hose ends go over the barbs, just for a bit of added security. A 1" hose clamp will adjust small enough to cover both the 3/4" and 7/8" connection with no issue, so a pair of them will be just fine. You'll probably want to be sure you've got one to attach the extender to the disposal intake as well. Better to spend an extra $2 (for expensive, fancy clamps) and not need them than to clean dirty, soapy water out from under the kitchen sink.

Comment: + for hose clamps, amazing how many don’t use them and the leak ruins the cabinets especially if made out of particle board.

Comment: Will the barbed connector crack the drain hose when I tighten the hose clamp? I'm also worried the rigid plastic hose won't seal properly against the rigid barbed adapter.